# Errors when configuring Apache Nutch crawler

Tags: java, nutch, web-crawler

I am having some trouble running Nutch on a Linux server. I am trying to crawl URLs configured in seed.txt, but I am seeing the following errors. The crawler is  triggered as follows

```
nohup java  -classpath "./common-conf/*:*:./plugins/*:" -jar  crawler-jar-2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar &
```

In this configuration, all the configuration properties are present in **common-conf** directory.  We have some custom configuration that we have set up in our Crawler binary. As a result, we have built a custom binary and don't use standard Apache nutch crawler. I see the following issues:

1. Our custom **nutch-default.xml** and **nutch-site.xml** are not picked from the **common-conf** classpath directory. They are being picked up from nutch jar file. When I print out the URL path for the both the xmls, I see something like this

   > nutch default =
   >   jar:file:/home/nbsxlwa/crawler/lib/nutch-2.2.1.jar!/nutch-default.xml
   >   nutch site =
   >   jar:file:/home/nbsxlwa/crawler/lib/nutch-2.2.1.jar!/nutch-site.xml

   I want the files to be picked up from classpath. I can verify that the files exist.
2. Our custom **gora.properties** is not being picked up. I see the following log trace

   > 14/08/22 07:18:24 WARN store.DataStoreFactory: gora.properties not found, properties will be empty.
   >   14/08/22 07:18:24 INFO crawl.InjectorJob: InjectorJob: Using class org.apache.gora.memory.store.MemStore as the Gora storage class.

   gora.properties exists in the classpath and I am not sure why it is not being picked up.

   ```
   /home/nbsxlwa/crawler/ find . -name "gora.properties"
   ./common-conf/gora.properties
   ```
3. **http.agent.name** configuration property is not being picked up. I can confirm that the configuration exists in nutch-site.xml

   The stack trace is given below.

   ```
   14/08/22 07:18:36 ERROR fetcher.FetcherJob: Fetcher: No agents listed in 'http.agent.name' property.
   14/08/22 07:18:36 WARN crawl.Crawler: Error running crawler job for configuration. Tool run command raises an exception
   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Fetcher: No agents listed in 'http.agent.name' property.
           at org.apache.nutch.fetcher.FetcherJob.checkConfiguration(FetcherJob.java:252)
           at org.apache.nutch.fetcher.FetcherJob.run(FetcherJob.java:160)
           at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.runTool(Crawler.java:78)
           at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.run(Crawler.java:176)
           at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.run(Crawler.java:266)
           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
           at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Crawler.main(Crawler.java:356)
   ```
4. **regex-normalize.xml** and **regex-urlfilter.txt** are not being picked up from the classpath. I can confirm that the files exist in my classpath. The stack trace is given below

   ```
   /home/nbsxlwa/crawler : find . -name "regex-normalize.xml"
   ./common-conf/regex-normalize.xml

   /home/nbsxlwa/crawler : find . -name "regex-urlfilter.txt"
   ./common-conf/regex-urlfilter.txt


   14/08/22 07:18:29 INFO conf.Configuration: regex-normalize.xml not found
   14/08/22 07:18:29 WARN regex.RegexURLNormalizer: Can't load the default rules! 
   14/08/22 07:18:29 INFO conf.Configuration: regex-urlfilter.txt not found
   14/08/22 07:18:29 INFO conf.Configuration: regex-normalize.xml not found
   14/08/22 07:18:29 WARN regex.RegexURLNormalizer: Can't load the default rules!
   ```

I have gone through the following links to see where I am going wrong. How do I set up Nutch configuration settings here?

1. http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/nutch-user/201202.mbox/%3CCAGaRif3rtJHokgG5FHSbnJLLUAVGiDnfx7JaW-7kiBjx_ivwSg@mail.gmail.com%3E and
2. http://osdir.com/ml/user.nutch.apache/2012-02/msg00127.html

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but thought it may help someone in the future:
Have you tried to run:
ant runtime
run it from the nutch folder after you changed the config values.